# How can I divide the available space in screen by 3*4 grid equally in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, components, styled-components

I am trying to divide the blue part of this screen by 3*4 grid,

[Screenshot of current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSleZ.png)

My problem here is the blue part in the bottom of screen, I dont know why is it like that even that I made 25% of inner containers height.

This is my code ( I used styled components ) :

Parent component :

```js
const SafeArea = styled(SafeAreaView)`
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: ${StatusBar.currentHeight}px;
`;

const SmallComponentsContainer = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

export const BiggerComponent = () => (
  <SafeArea>
    <Text> header 1 </Text>
    <Text> Heaader 2 </Text>
    <SmallComponentsContainer>
      <SmallerComponent test={1} />
      <SmallerComponent test={2} />
      <SmallerComponent test={3} />
      <SmallerComponent test={4} />
      <SmallerComponent test={5} />
      <SmallerComponent test={6} />
      <SmallerComponent test={7} />
      <SmallerComponent test={8} />
      <SmallerComponent test={9} />
      <SmallerComponent test={10} />
      <SmallerComponent test={11} />
      <SmallerComponent test={12} />
    </SmallComponentsContainer>
  </SafeArea>
);
```

Child component :

```js
const ViewComp = styled.View`
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 25%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: gray;
`;

export const SmallerComponent = ({ test }) => {
  return (
    <ViewComp>
      `your text`
      <Text>{test}</Text>
    </ViewComp>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed that `aspect-ratio: 1;` part from `ViewComp` component and everything went okay, this is what I wanted to achieve :

[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyq9A.png)